# Creating a Java InputStream from an Enumerator[Array[Byte]]

Tags: java, scala, playframework, io, loops

I've been reading up a lot on Iteratees & Enumerators in order to implement a new module in my application.

I'm now at a point where I'm integrating with a 3rd party Java library, and am stuck at working with this method:

```
public Email addAttachment(String name, InputStream file) throws IOException {
    this.attachments.put(name, file);
    return this;
}
```

What I have in my API is the body returned from a `WS` HTTP call that is an `Enumerator[Array[Byte]]`.

I am wondering now how to write an `Iteratee` that would process the chunks of `Array[Bytes]` and create an `InputStream` to use in this method.

*(Side bar): There are other versions of the `addAttachment` method that take `java.io.File` however I want to avoid writing to the disk in this operation, and would rather deal with streams.*

I attempted to start by writing something like this:

```
Iteratee.foreach[Array[Byte]] { bytes =>
    ???
}
```

However I'm not sure how to interact with the java `InputStream` here. I found something called a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) however that takes the entire `Array[Byte]` in its constructor, which I'm not sure would work in this scenario as I'm working with chunks ?

I probably need some Java help here!

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This is a difficult one. I think your best bet is to create an implementation of the InputStream interface with the underlying enumerator. And then on every `read` call, consume the necessary amount of bytes from the Enumerator.

Comment: Other than that, I think your best bet is caching everything and feeding it into a ByteArrayInputStream. The problem is, Enumerator is a flow of data with a push mechanic and InputStream uses a pull mechanic, which means, you need to have a buffer somewhere otherwise this isn't going to work. You can buffer everything for now, and maybe decide later, what to do when performance is becoming a bottleneck. Maybe do partial buffers, you get the point.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but I tried something like this:

`val consume = body |>>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()`

Then `new ByteArrayInputStream(consume)` later on.

I think this is a naive implementation of your second comment, however without the buffering.

Comment: I can look if I can put something together later tonight. I don't know how long this WS api will last though. Heard something about Akka streams being implemented soon into Play.

Comment: I will try something also. I'm calling my own service that generates PDF documents and I then pull them over http. Oh so they're planning to remove 'getStream' from the WS api?

Comment: I heard something like that yeah. Should be really interesting though. I definitely prefer the idea of push and pull combined and a lot of smart guys work on it which should be a recipe for success.

Comment: @Michael Kendra Hi I'm also facing the same issue as i'm new to scala play I can't able to get a solution Have you got a solution pls help me too resolve this issue

Answer (score 3):

If I'm following you, I think you want to work with PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html

You always use them in pairs.  You can construct the pair like so:

```
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(); //can also specify a buffer size
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputSream(in);
```

Pass the input stream to the API, and in your own code iterate through your chucks and write your bytes.

The only caveat is that you need to read/write in separate threads.  In your case, its probably good to do your iterating / writing in a separate thread.  I'm sure you can handle it in Scala better than me, in Java it would be something like:

```
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(); //can also specify a buffer size
PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputSream(out);
new Thread(() -> {
  // do your looping in here, write to 'out'
  out.close();
}).run();
email.addAttachment(in);
email.send();
in.close();
```

(Leaving out exception handling & resource handling for clarity)